# How to I block a yahoo contact that is spamming me in Messages application?

Tags: macos

How to I block a **Yahoo messenger** contact that is spamming me in Messages application?

I tried `Buddied > Remove buddy` but it has not effect.

Do I really have to install the  Yahoo! client in order to do that or there are alternatives to this?

Comment: More than an year later, the history repeats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no blocking mechanism built into iOS 6 and lower or on OS X.

On iOS 7, you can add contacts to a block list and not receive calls, FaceTime, or messages from that contact (and the rest that you block).

From the settings app, use iMessage and FaceTime preferences to add numbers to a block list.

[image: iOS 7 call blocking settings]

---

On OS X or iOS before iOS 6, You will have to convince that person to stop sending messages or stop using that account.

Comment: I installed the ***** Yahoo messenger just for blocking the account.

Comment: Oh nice - I missed that it could be an old school iChat type message - perhaps I best edit the answer.

Comment: I just hope people will not start sending spam using iMessage as it may become a real nightmare as I do not know any way of blocking them... and I will get the spam on 3 devices at a time: MBP, iPad and iPhone!!!